# Are there any other Java libraries for bonjour/zeroconf apart from JMDNS?

Tags: java, bonjour, zeroconf

Are there any other Java libraries for bonjour/zeroconf apart from JMDNS?

Comment: What's wrong with [JMDNS](http://www.jmdns.org)? (after they moved to github ;-)

Answer (score 36):

I'm also curious to find the best cross-platform DNS-SD (Zeroconf, Bonjour, DNS self discovery) library exists out there.

It does sound like [Apple's DNS-SD dnssd.jar](http://developer.apple.com/networking/bonjour/index.html) is the "official" Java library that requires native library support on Windows, Linux, etc, but works out of the box on Mac OSX.

There are other pure Java DNS-SD implementations, but it's unclear if any of them offer a library that is as easy to use or fully tested as DNS-SD (some of the projects appear to be abandoned for 2 years).

1. [Official Apple DNS-SD mDNSResponder
   library](http://developer.apple.com/networking/bonjour/index.html)
2. [mDNSResponder and jmDNS
   integration](http://www.offthehill.org/articles/2008/01/08/a-jmdns-mdnsresponder-zeroconf-compatibility-interface/) - There's been some
   work to create a library that
   provides a common DNS-SD interface
   to jmDNS and Apple's mDNSResponder
   implementation. [Instructions to use
   the jmDNS wrapper](http://www.offthehill.org/articles/2008/01/10/how-to-use-the-java-mdns-wrapper/).
3. [waiter](http://code.google.com/p/waiter/) - Described as a "modern
   DNS library and an effective DNS-SD
   (Service Discovery) library." It
   utilizes java NIO networking.
4. [jmDNS](http://www.jmdns.org/) - JmDNS provides
   easy-to-use pure-Java mDNS
   implementation that runs on JDK 1.4
   and higher
5. [JiveDNS](http://www.java.net/project/multicast-dns-and-dns-sd-library) - "JiveDNS is a fork of
   the defunct JmDNS library, used for
   multicast DNS service discovery and
   registration." (it itself has not
   seen an SVN update in over 2 years)

Comment: Another excellent summary: http://elliotth.blogspot.com/2009/03/registering-service-with-dns-sd-from.html

Comment: Thorbjørn, could you point me to some code in the Eclipse code base where it's used. This would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @Johnny, I believe it is used in the Eclipse Communication Framework - http://www.eclipse.org/ecf/ - but I d o not have personal experience with it.

Comment: JmDNS does not work nicely. I am investigating a severe bug where it announces on the wrong IP address for the interface and it's such a horrible kind of bug that I'm willing to hop libraries to get away from it rather than fixing it. Also the maintainers for the library have set the permissions on their bug tracker so that you can't file new bugs against it, which is scummy behaviour.

Comment: Should throw in that mDNS support in waiter appears to be a TODO ("need a way of registering broadcast records") so it is no replacement for JmDNS. At least not yet. :( There is also another library for DNS-SD called dnssdjava which appears to have a fairly sensible API for everything but then also lacks multicast support, meaning that it is no replacement either. :(

Comment: As mentioned below by @carl, it look like Apple's DNS-SD jar is no longer available. dougnukem, could mention that in the answer, to make it stand out more. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

mdnsjava is a project that provides mDNS and DNS-SD support for dnsjava (dnsjava.org). 
Unlike many of the DNS-SD java implementations mdnsjava supports full mDNS DNS RR resolution, not just the resolution of services.

https://code.google.com/p/mdnsjava/

Comment: With mdnsjava: How do you bind to a specific network interface only?

Comment: Hey posicks, can you have a look at this question please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482168/dns-sd-experience-with-mdnsjava

Answer (score 2):

Try at:

[DNS-SD](http://www.java2s.com/Article/Java/Development/API.htm)

-- The same Java DNS-SD APIs are also available in Bonjour for Windows, Bonjour for Linux, Solaris, *BSD, etc., enabling Java software to make use of Zeroconf's DNS Service Discovery across a wide range of platforms, not just on Mac OS X ......

Answer (score 2):

Waiter seems to be a pure Java library for DNS-SD.  It's available here:

http://code.google.com/p/waiter/

Answer (score 1):

Unless your goal is to announce service availability to other mDNS compatible applications or to consume mDNS services from other applications, it might make more sense to implement your own broadcast-based service discovery.

Answer (score 1):

dns_sd.jar on windows works fine, download from Apple (SDK for windows). Beware of reinstallations of Bonjour because they tend to overwrite the Program Files/Bonjour directory containing the dns_sd.jar. Airfoil from Rogue Amoeba is one example on this, however they claim to use the Apple original installer.

dnssd.jar on OSX works fine, but is no longer included in the latest Java releases as Oracle has taken over responsibility. However, the file is still on the disk since the 1.6 Java of Apple is on the disk. Just find the file and move it to /externals folder in your latest Java. So it is quite funny-idiotic that Apple provides a well functioning SDK for Windows implementation of Java DNS SD, while not offering anything at all for their own OSX. I anticipate that this is simply the result of hating Java too much over at Apple?

But, does anyone know of a Java implementation of the airtunes protocol; the latest version used in today´s Airport Express and Apple TV, being NOT the same version as used in earlier models of Airport Express ?

I know of qTunes, but it does not work with latest Airtunes versions. (I could get it to work with Rogue Amoeba´s Airfoil speakers for Mac OS X)

I am not monitoring this thread, but can be contacted at chj@hdsoundlab.com for practical questions.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a simple, pure Java implementation of mDNS Service Discovery. At the moment only synchronous browsing is supported, but I plan to add an asynchronous listener in the next release. It's free software and available on GitHub at https://github.com/fflewddur/hola.

The only requirements are Java 8 and having the [slf4j-api](http://www.slf4j.org/) available in your class path.

Answer (score 0):

I've found more easy to create my own implementation (after experience with WS-Discovery and Bonjour for cross-platform cases) https://github.com/4ntoine/ServiceDiscovery-java. It has both Java and iOS impl for both client and server side.

Answer (score 0):

Try avahi4j (https://code.google.com/archive/p/avahi4j/). But the project is archived and there is no active development from 2009.