# How to discover all the available IP addresses of the web-server?

Tags: java, java-me

How to detect ( discover ) all of the web-servers by using j2me ? I mean that the web-servers are inside a LAN.

Comment: LAN of what ? please clarify your Q

Comment: @Jigar Joshi : a LAN of computers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are not interested in asking every IP address or named host from the list hard-coded into an app.

You may find [Zeroconf](http://www.zeroconf.org/) protocol useful. It is suited for discovering of available services with the means of broadcast or multicast IP packets.

[Debian Wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/ZeroConf) page has some links to Zeroconf software, including [libapache2-mod-dnssd](http://packages.debian.org/stable/libapache2-mod-dnssd).

As for client part, maybe this will help: [Are there any other Java libraries for bonjour/zeroconf apart from JMDNS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233204/are-there-any-other-java-libraries-for-bonjour-zeroconf-apart-from-jmdns)