# What defines a "direct communication" between 2 computers ( or a phone and a computer ) ? for UDP (or TCP ) communication?

Tags: android, tcp, wifi, android-wifi

I want to write a program to access my Android phone's camera on my laptop wirelessly, so, my phone will act like a wireless webcam. 
I want to implement the UDP ( or TCP ) protocol in Java to communicate between my laptop and phone.

I was thinking of making an ad-hoc wireless network in my laptop and connecting my phone to it first, and then write the code to create a server socket on my laptop and client socket on my phone.
I know this code will work for a "direct communication" between server and client. but will this method of ad-hoc network communication count as a "direct communication" ?
If not, what do I do to achieve this ?

Thank you, firstly for reading my whole problem,  and,
thanks a lot if you can answer this for me

:)

Comment: It might be easier to answer this question if I knew what you meant by 'direct communication'.  This is certainly one of the more direct ways to communicate between your phone and computer, although I suppose USB or something might be closer to what you call 'direct communication', but then you wouldn't be using either UDP or TCP.

Comment: how about the gc2dm or the way ESfileExplorer app connects with computer via LAN.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Don't concentrate on ad-hoc networks. In most cases WiFi with infrastructure mode access points will be available. If on the road, all recent versions of Android are able to act as a wireless access point.

So let's assume both devices are connected to the same network and are able to reach each other (using the IP protocol) - in other word they are able to `ping` each other. The next issue you have to solve is: How do both applications find each other? Bonjour/Zeroconf might be a solution (see [Are there any other Java libraries for bonjour/zeroconf apart from JMDNS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233204)).

The next question is: What protocol you want to use? You mentioned TCP and UDP. In most cases UDP will be used for transmitting video data, because you have a lower latency and the video codecs are tolerant on missing packets.

With this information you can create a `ServerSocket` and (from the client side) know where to connect to it.

Comment: thank you. I was thinking in a similar way, to implement sockets in java via. UDP. I was thinking of using the 'vlcj' libraries to reconstruct the frames that are sent.