# mDNS code bonjour

Tags: java, service-discovery, mdns

I need to develop some server  discovery protocol , I tried to get the mDNS document where I can understand about mDNS and its implementation . but I could not get .. Can any one help me to get the same and basic code would help me a lot ..

I'm planning to implement the discovery protocol using JAVA .

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233204/are-there-any-other-java-libraries-for-bonjour-zeroconf-apart-from-jmdns

Comment: So which paper are you looking for? Maybe this: http://www.multicastdns.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search reveals:

- http://code.google.com/p/mahalo-mdns/
- http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/